# How to get new code running

Tags: javascript, express

I'm new to web development and so am following a course. It's an intro to expressjs and so while trying to run some code I'm getting an error.

my code in js:

```
    const express=require('express');
const server=express();
server.get('/',function(req,res,next){
    res.send("Hello World")
})

server.get('/greet/:name',function(req,res,next){
    let greeting="Good Morning, "+ req.params.name;
     res.send(greeting)
})

server.listen(2121);
```

The error is when I open a new tab in chrome with url:  http://localhost:2121/greet/a

**I get a white screen with this written:**

> Cannot GET /greet/a

Help! Thanks :)

Comment: This works fine, did you restart your node application?

Comment: install nodemon: `sudo npm i -g nodemon`  and run: `nodemon app.js` it will autorestart app when You change code.

Comment: restart ? no and why should I?

Comment: ok ill try that and see if it works

Comment: ti's long to explain, watch this: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nodemon+tutorial

Comment: if You're using windows, then: `npm i -g nodemon`

Comment: If you do changes to the code while the appllication is running then those won't have any effect until you restart the application, there is no hot reloading. The shown code works without any problems, so the only explanation is that you had the server running while you did changes and did not restart it.

Comment: how to restart node application without installing nodemon?

Comment: @AkhilVaid that depens on how you started it. If you started it in the commandline using `node filename.js`  then you would hit `ctrl - c` to stop it. And then start it again.

Comment: im coding in vscode. i just saved the file then went to chrome and typed localhost.... and tried it

Comment: vscode does not magically start your application, you either have clicked e.g. the green play button, started the node application in the terminal of vscode or defined another way to start it. If you don't know how you started the node application how should we know how to restart it?

Comment: ok i clicked the play button too. then i tried the control c thing , it terminated then i wrote in vscode terminal node server.js as server.js is my file name. then i went goog chrome and opened new tab, still doesnt work. Im sorry if im frustating you. :/

Comment: How did you **first** start the application in vscode. `i just saved the file then went to chrome and typed localhost` alone would not start the application. So what did you do that your node applicationw as started?

Comment: woah. i closed vscode then switched it on now it works. wtf. I dont think this shouldve been the solution

Comment: Do not write the solution in your question. Use the answer section for answers.

Comment: Exiting vscode will also stop all running child process (including your server), so yes this is also one possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that I didn't restart my code before trying to run the server again. I solved this by intuitively **closing my editor and restarting it**. Another Way that I found to solve this was by using the combination **ctrl+alt+m to terminate previous code** that was running.

Thank you guys for down-voting a beginners questions. **Much appreciated!**

Now I'm somehow banned from asking any future questions.

**Cheers <3**